# How the optimal value of jumping block size is found in jump search?

Tags: algorithm

The value of the function `((n/m) + m-1)` will be minimum when `m = √n`. Therefore, the best step size is `m = √n`.
Here, `n` is size of array and `m` is block size to be jumped.

I understood that `n/m` is the jumps that we make for the worst case, `m-1` is the times that is taken for linear search once we find the interval `(arr[km] < x < arr[(k+1)m])`.

But i don't understand how `m=√n` is found. I'm trying as below.

```
(n/m)+m-1=0;
(n/m)+m=1;
n+m^2=m;
n=m-m^2.
```

But how does this become `m = m=√n`

Comment: Do `m` and `n` have any bounds? The result of the function has no minimum if `n` can be negative and arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want to find the minimum for any `n`.

```
(n/m)+m-1
```

The minimum is where the gradient is 0.

So differentiate the expression with respect to `m`:

```
d/dm (n/m)+m-1 = 1-n/m^2
```

And solving `1-n/m^2 = 0` gives you `m = sqrt(n)`

Comment: can you please help me to understand this line -> d/dm (n/m)+m-1 = 1-n/m^2

Comment: How much do you understand about differentiation?

Comment: It's easier if you rearrange it: `n*m^-1 + m - 1`, then to differentiate, do  each term: `-n*m^-2 + 1`